# Rotating Labels

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, label

I have a need to rotate editable labels in IB - I'm aware that you cannot rotate in Interface Builder itself. However, does anyone have any info on how to do this via xcode? Hopefully it's not too daunting as I'm new to cocoa : / Any help would be appreciated!

Zach

Comment: first you need to import quartz framework in your class file and after that you need to use the layer property to rotate the label

Answer (score 1):

See `NSView`'s -`setBoundsRotation` method.

Comment: `NSTextField` inherits from `NSView`, so you can use that property.