# Quartz Framework (Mac) Explanation Needed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, quartz-graphics

I have some labels I need to be rotated, and I asked a question earlier about how to do so:

[Rotating Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998229/rotating-labels)

Apparently the best way to do this is via the layer property of the Quartz Framework? Can someone give a newbie an explanation on how to do this? :) I will award an answer quickly!

Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `NSView`'s `setBoundsRotation:` method to set it without CoreAnimation.

If you really want to use CoreAnimation you would go like this:

```
// make NSView myView a layer-backed view
[myView setWantsLayer:YES];
// now get that CALayer and set the affineTransform of it, specifying the angle
[myView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
```

Answer (score 0):

layer is a property of UIView and gives you an object of type CALayer to which you can apply a transformation, like

```
CALayer* layer = theLabel.layer;
[layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
```

which will give you an upside down label.

Comment: Ooops, this is Mac! No `UIView`. ;-)

Comment: On the Mac you can set the NSView to be layer backed (with setWantsLayer: if doing programmatically, otherwise there's a check box in Interface Builder), in which case it has a layer property, exposing a CALayer on which setAffineTransform should work.

Comment: @Bavarious: Would you mind elaborating on how to use this? I don't understand how to implement this into my interface